# "clear shopping cart" and "continue shopping" buttons are not coming in checkout page in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

I want to display "clear shopping cart" and "continue shopping" buttons on my checkout page. But i dont see configurations for the same.
i checked the /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml and in this buttons are der . But i dont know how to configure them.
plz help

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Their is 3 case

1 -> Go to view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml under which theme you used.
Then Check on that before clear shopping cart button

```
  if ($block->getViewModel()->isClearShoppingCartEnabled()) 

remove this condition . It Shows.
```

2-> If You used default luma theme Then Please remove above condition on form.phtml

3-> .cart-container .form-cart .actions.main .continue { display: none; }
you can overwrite this by display:block ,

for Continue Shopping

```
.cart-container .form-cart .actions.main .continue {display: block !important;}
```

For Clear Shopping Cart

```
.cart-container .form-cart .actions.main #empty_cart_button {display: block !imortant;
```

}

Comment: I think that the condition should stay in place and give a more flexibility to decide whether you want to display the continue URL or not, by customizing the functionality and add an admin configuration. Also, your PHP code line is from Magento 2.4.

Comment: Yes You are right . but if any problem to filter this (after enable clear shopping cart on admin configuration ) that is the solution to remove it .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these options are available in the cart page, so basically that's where you will find them (not the checkout page). Secondly, they are styled as links by default.

For the **'continue shopping'** one I think you need to write some code to enable this functionality. If you check the method `getContinueShoppingUrl()` mentioned at line 52 of your printscreen, you will see the following:

[image]

The solution that I see, is to set the *'continue_shopping_url'* property on the cart object by custom code (controlled by a custom admin configuration show/hide), probably via **an observer**, after adding products to cart. You will have to decide which is the URL to add (it can be anything from the homepage URL as in old versions of Magento, to the referrer URL or a custom setting).

However, if you don't intend to use the referrer and your continue shopping URL is a fixed one, I would probably go with a more permanent solution and change the behavior of this method via **a plugin** (but keeping the same idea that you can control by admin config whether you want to show it or not).

The checkout session property seen in my printscreen is used in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart.php` `getBackUrl()` method called by the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php`action, where it handles the case where you should remain on the page you added the product to cart from (as per Magento configuration) so it has implicity the value of the referrer URL.